# Reset the counter value

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
var sum = 0;

function OnChange(value) {
  sum += parseInt(value);
  var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("second").value;
  document.getElementById("firstOutput").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("secondOutput").innerHTML = y;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<select id="first" onchange='OnChange(this.value)'>
  <option>Choose...</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="1">
    first
  </option>
  <option class="form-control" value="2">
    second
  </option>
</select>
<select id="second" onchange='OnChange(this.value)'>
  <option>Choose...</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="1">
    first
  </option>
  <option class="form-control" value="2">
    second
  </option>
</select>
<a id="firstOutput"></a>
<a id="firstOutput"></a>
<a id="total"></a>
```

which is not working how I want.

If select on option on every select option the calculation is working, but if change the option is continue to calculate, how to make calculation if change just one option and not to add more just to change the value for changed option.

Comment: `var z -> var y` `<a id="firstOutput"></a> -> <a id="secondOutput"></a>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood, you want your script to get the 1st and 2nd select values, and then calculate the total, if it is the case you have some mistakes:

1. you declared `z` instead of `y`
2. you gave the same `id` to your both `<a>` elements ( `firstOutput`,`secondOutput` )
3. You initialised `sum` outside the function, so it will always increase starting from the last value
4. Your option "Choose" has no default value

Here's a working code

```js
function OnChange(value) {
  var sum = 0;
  var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
  sum = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
  document.getElementById("firstOutput").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("secondOutput").innerHTML = y;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<select id="first" onchange='OnChange(this.value)'>
  <option value="0">Choose...</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="1">
    first
  </option>
  <option class="form-control" value="2">
    second
  </option>
</select>
<select id="second" onchange='OnChange(this.value)'>
  <option value="0">Choose...</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="1">
    first
  </option>
  <option class="form-control" value="2">
    second
  </option>
</select>
<br>
First select: <a id="firstOutput"></a>
<br>
Second select: <a id="secondOutput"></a>
<br>
Total: <a id="total"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code

1. You've used `y` which is not defined. So according to your code snippet, you should use `z`.
   `document.getElementById("secondOutput").innerHTML = z;`
2. You've defined 2 `a` tag with the same `id="firstOutput"`

```js
function OnChange(value) {  
  var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("second").value;
  
  document.getElementById("firstOutput").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("secondOutput").innerHTML = z;
  const sum = parseInt(x) + parseInt(z);
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<select id="first" onchange='OnChange(this.value)'>
    <option value="0">Choose...</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="1">
      first
    </option>
    <option class="form-control" value="2">
      second
    </option>
  </select>
  <select id="second" onchange='OnChange(this.value)'>
    <option value="0">Choose...</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="1">
      first
    </option>
    <option class="form-control" value="2">
      second
    </option>
  </select>
  <a id="firstOutput"></a>
  <a id="secondOutput"></a>
  <a id="total"></a>
```

Comment: This fails if I pick "Choose..." again

Comment: Thanks, @MarkSchultheiss for pointing this bug. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

1. I would remove the change hook from the markup and put it in your script.
2. I would use a loop to attach the change event handler - I used a `choice` class to make it generic and not have to alter script if I add another option list for example
3. Sometimes a `<select>` is multiple, so I allowed for that `<select multiple>`
4. Now I loop through, find all selected options and add them up for your `sum`
5. I also filtered by your class on options so I can ignore the `Choose....` but there are several ways to do that, I just build on your class `form-control`, filter on those that are selected and do the loop
6. I do not know why you used an anchor tag `<a>` but it seems wrong, and was missing an attribute `ref="#"` so I swapped it out with a `div` which makes more sense in this case
7. I altered the HTML to be valid (no duplicate ID's)
8. I put the "sum" inside but it could be set to 0 if it were defined elsewhere if needed.

```js
const choiceElement = document.querySelectorAll('.choice');
choiceElement.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    var sum = 0;
    const result = document.querySelector('.result');
    result.textContent = `You like ${event.target.value} of #${event.target.id}`;
    choiceElement.forEach((choice) => {
      const options = choice.options;
      const selectedOptions = [...options]
        .filter(el => {
          return el.matches(".form-control")
        })
        .filter(option => option.selected);
      selectedOptions.forEach((opt) => {
        sum = sum + parseInt(opt.value, 10);
      })
      //   }
    });
    document.getElementById("total-value").textContent = sum;
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="firstc" class='choice'>
  <option>Choose...</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="1">first</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="2">second</option>
</select>
<select id="secondc" class='choice'>
  <option>Choose...</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="1">first</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="2">second</option>
</select>
<select id="i-wonder-what" class='choice' multiple>
  <option>Choose...</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="1">first</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="2">two</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="4">Double 2</option>
  <option class="form-control" value="9">nine</option>
</select>
<div id="firstOutput"></div>
<div id="secondOutput"></div>
<div id="total">Total: <span id="total-value"></span></div>
<div class="result">tellme</div>
```

Comment: I left out any reference to syntax errors from the original question with this rework

Answer (score -1):

You have not defined y
You have defined z and using y

Correct Code shall be :

```js
var sum = 0;

function OnChange(value) {
  sum += parseInt(value);
  var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
  document.getElementById("firstOutput").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("secondOutput").innerHTML = y;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

Comment: What about the `a` with the same `id="firstOutput"`. As per your solution program runs fine but not what @krasiit intended.