# Pass value number and image from select option to javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony

I'm new to javascript. I try to pass value and image to javascript to display image on a tag and summarize the value. This link is helped me to summarize
[Helped link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185542/reset-the-counter-value/66186026?noredirect=1#comment117013359_66186026). But I don't now how to pass the image every time when I change the option. I have this from backend.

```js
function OnChange(value) {
  var sum = 0;
  var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
  sum = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
  document.getElementById("firstOutput").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("secondOutput").innerHTML = y;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<select id="first" onchange='OnChange(this.value)'>
  <option value="0">Choose...</option>
  {% for number in numbers %}
    <option class="form-control" value="{{number.value}}">
      {{number.name}}
    </option>
  {%endfor%}  
</select>
<select id="second" onchange='OnChange(this.value)'>
  <option value="0">Choose...</option>
  {% for bigNumber in bigNumbers %}
    <option class="form-control" value="{{bigNumber.value}}">
      {{bigNumber.name}}
    </option>
  {%endfor%}  
</select>
<br>
First select: <a id="firstOutput"></a>
Image: <a id="firstImage"></a><!-- MISSING IMAGE -->
<br>
Second select: <a id="secondOutput"></a>
Image: <a id="secondImage"></a><!-- MISSING IMAGE -->
<br>
Total: <a id="total"></a>
```

How to pass the `{{number.image}}` and `{{bigNumber.image}}` to another javascript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for information.

I found another way to solve my task.

I added in the value - two values

```
value="{{number.image}}{{bigNumber.image}}"
```

and then in javascript I just use

```
split(" ")
```

and the use like array.

```
 x[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: instead of trying to pass `number.image` or `bigNumber.image` to your javascript you could:

1. loop through them in your `html`
2. add `style="display:none"` to hide them
3. add a unique `id="firstImage_"` + `{{number.value}}`
4. in your `onChange` function, hide all images, then display the ones selected

```js
function OnChange(value) {
  var sum = 0;
  var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
  sum = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
  document.getElementById("firstOutput").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("secondOutput").innerHTML = y;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
  // hide all images
  document.getElementsByClassName('image').style.display = 'none';
  // show the selected ones
  document.getElementById('firstImage_'+x).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('secondImage_'+y).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
First select: <a id="firstOutput"></a>
Image: 
{% for number in numbers %}
 <a class="image" style="display:none" id="firstImage_{{number.value}}"> 
   <img src="{{number.image}}"/>
 </a><!-- MISSING IMAGE -->
{%endfor%}
<br>
Second select: <a id="secondOutput"></a>
Image: 
{% for bigNumber in bigNumbers %}
 <a style="display:none" class="image" id="secondImage_{{number.value}}">
   <img src="{{bigNumber.image}}"/>
 </a><!-- MISSING IMAGE -->
{%endfor%}
<br>
Total: <a id="total"></a>
```

Comment: I tried but in dev tool show every time the same image when I change the option. If understand I need to loop again whenre I need to show the image.

Comment: You don't have to loop again, in the first loop you should have all your picture in your html but hidden ( try to check on dev tools the existence of hidden images ) then with JavaScript each time you change the id according to the selected option.

Comment: Yes I can see all pictures in dev tools, but each time when I change the option can't see the image and I try to show the image outside of the loop.